# Problemas usando NextAuth: no valida las credenciales username y password

Tags: reactjs, next.js, auth

mi problema es el siguiente.
Tengo implementado NextAuth en mi proyecto con Next 13 con TypeScript.
En la implementación actual, tanto si uso credenciales válidas como no válidas, no realiza el login y direccionamiento.
He estado leyendo documentación y viendo tutoriales durante un mes y no logro sacar.
Imprimo los console logs y en todo momento la respuesta indica status 200, pero no es la respuesta del servidor.

Esto es: /api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts

```
const handler = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        username: { label: "Username", type: "text", placeholder: "test@test.com" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const res = await fetch(
          `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL}/auth/login`,
          {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({
              username: credentials?.username,
              password: credentials?.password,
            }),
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          }
        );
        console.log(res);
        
        const user = await res.json();
        
        if (user.error) throw user;

        return user;
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      return { ...token, ...user };
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      session.user = token as any;
      return session;
    },
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/",
  },
});
```

El console.log(res) no imprime nada.

Y en el componente login:

```
const [credentials, setCredentials] = useState({
      username: "", 
      password: "",
    });

  const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Acá');
    
    try {
      const response = await signIn("credentials", {
        username: credentials.username,
        password: credentials.password,
        redirect: false,
      });
    
      console.log(response);
    
      if (response && response.status == 200) {
        router.push("/");
      } else {
        console.log("Credenciales Inválidas");
        setErrors("Credenciales Inválidas");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error en el inicio de sesión: ", error);
      setErrors("Error en el inicio de sesión");
    }
    }
```

Después de enviar el form, imprime el console.log `Acá`, y el objeto con status 200, que no es del servidor. Pero no ingresa a la app.
En mi archivo .env tengo configurado el NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL y el NEXTAUTH_SECRET.
No es un problema de servidor por qué si hago la peticion normalmente, está todo ok e ingresa a la app.

Gracias de antemano.